Gmail add on compose trigger fails with missing properties of event object
I'm creating a simple script that, when I click on the add-on it should get the e-mail's content and just show them. But, when I click the add-on icon that  appears in the compose and reply options in Gmail I don't get the content. I only get the content when I click on the one, that is on the side what is the issue?

Error Info Event object: undefined, Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'gmail')

This is the code

/**
 * Function to build the compose UI.
 *
 * @param {Object} e The event object.
 * @return {CardService.Card[]} The card to show to the user.
 */
function getComposeUI(e) {
  Logger.log('getComposeUI event: ' + JSON.stringify(e));

  var subject = 'No Subject';
  var sender = 'Unknown Sender';
  var body = 'No content available';

  // Check if the compose action is triggered
  if (e && e.action && e.action.compose) {
    var action = e.action.compose;
    var actionParameters = action.parameters;

    // Check if the action type is "REPLY" or "FORWARD"
    if (actionParameters && actionParameters.action == 'REPLY' || actionParameters.action == 'FORWARD') {
      // Get the message ID of the original email
      var messageId = actionParameters.messageId;
      var message = GmailApp.getMessageById(messageId);

      subject = message.getSubject() || 'No Subject';
      sender = message.getFrom() || 'Unknown Sender';
      body = message.getPlainBody() || 'No content available';
      Logger.log('Reply or Forward action. Subject: ' + subject + ', Sender: ' + sender + ', Body: ' + body);
    } else {
      Logger.log('New message action.');
    }
  } else {
    Logger.log('No relevant event data found.');
  }

  var card = buildComposeCard(subject, sender, body);
  return [card];
}

/**
 * Function to build the compose card.
 *
 * @param {string} subject The subject of the email.
 * @param {string} sender The sender of the email.
 * @param {string} body The body of the email.
 * @return {CardService.Card}
 */
function buildComposeCard(subject, sender, body) {
  Logger.log('Building compose card with subject: ' + subject + ', sender: ' + sender + ', body: ' + body);

  var card = CardService.newCardBuilder()
    .setHeader(CardService.newCardHeader().setTitle('Email Content'))
    .addSection(CardService.newCardSection()
      .addWidget(CardService.newTextParagraph().setText('Subject: ' + subject))
      .addWidget(CardService.newTextParagraph().setText('Sender: ' + sender))
      .addWidget(CardService.newTextParagraph().setText('Body: ' + body)))
    .build();

  return card;
}

/**
 * Trigger function when a Gmail message is opened.
 * Constructs the add-on's user interface for the message.
 */
function onGmailMessageOpen(e) {
  Logger.log('onGmailMessageOpen event: ' + JSON.stringify(e));

  var subject = 'No Subject';
  var sender = 'Unknown Sender';
  var body = 'No content available';

  if (e && e.gmail && e.gmail.messageId) {
    var messageId = e.gmail.messageId;
    var message = GmailApp.getMessageById(messageId);

    subject = message.getSubject() || 'No Subject';
    sender = message.getFrom() || 'Unknown Sender';
    body = message.getPlainBody() || 'No content available';
  } else {
    Logger.log('No relevant event data found.');
  }

  var card = buildComposeCard(subject, sender, body);
  return [card];
}


This is the manifest file:
{
  "timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles",
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": []
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.execute",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.action.compose",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly"
  ],
  "gmail": {
    "name": "Email Content Viewer",
    "logoUrl": "https://example.com/logo.png",
    "contextualTriggers": [
      {
        "unconditional": {},
        "onTriggerFunction": "onGmailMessageOpen"
      }
    ],
    "composeTrigger": {
      "selectActions": [
        {
          "text": "Get Email Content",
          "runFunction": "getComposeUI"
        }
      ]
    },
    "openLinkUrlPrefixes": [
      "https://"
    ],
    "primaryColor": "#4285F4",
    "secondaryColor": "#D2E3FC"
  }
}


I tried changing the manifest file, the permissions, but nothing worked.

Which line throws the error?

this is what i get in the log now
8:36:54 PM Info getComposeUI event: undefined
8:36:54 PM Info No relevant event data found.
8:36:54 PM Info Building compose card with subject: No Subject, sender: Unknown Sender, body: No content available
